# Triangle Inequality and absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

I'm curious if the triangle inequality (and reverse triangle inequality) still hold if we only take the absolute value of one term. For example:

$$||a| - b| \le |a - b|$$

If $b \ge 0$, then $|b|$ is the same due to the definition of absolute value. I am unsure and am having trouble finding (or proving myself) if the inequality still holds if $b \lt 0$.

Comment: Did you test your hypothesis for some simple cases?

Comment: So why didn't you just test it for _some_ $b\lt 0$...???

Comment: oops, sorry, looks like i made a computation mistake early on when testing it (-10 and -3) and then tried to find a way to prove it before double checking my computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a=-1, b=-1$ looks like the counterexample here since

$$||a|-b|=||-1|-(-1)| = |1+1|=2$$
and
$$|a-b|=|-1-(-1)|=|0|=0$$

---

A more general hint: To find a counterexample in this and similar cases, I would first try the following four options:

$$a=1,b=1\\ a=-1, b=1\\a=1, b=-1\\a=-1, b=-1$$